# how to deal with the Broken pipe with python and thrift

Tags: python, thrift

I am new about thrift and socket.I build a server by thrift with python.the code like this：

```
class HelloServiceHandler:
    def buildIndex(self, fileData):
        tem = index.SaveIndex(fileData.name)
        tem.build_index(3)
        return True

handler = HelloServiceHandler()
processor = ReIndex.Processor(handler)
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket("0.0.0.0", 9090)
tfactory = TTransport.TFramedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TCompactProtocol.TCompactProtocolFactory()

server = TServer.TThreadPoolServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

print ("Starting thrift server in python...")
server.serve()
print ("done!")
```

when client run, the server often got error `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`， it seems like the problem of thread.

so how to modify code ?

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to close and re-open the transport in such cases. This is pretty much true for all Thrift languages I have dealt with so far, so it should be true with Python as well.